# Loading a Xamarin project into Visual Studio breaks all it's keyboard shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin-studio

When loading a *Xamarin* project into *VS*, all the shortcuts stop working. No <kbd>F5</kbd>, no nothing.

**Scenario**

Say intellisense shows it's recommendations while you're typing however the common Tab key doesn't complete what you've started and recommended by intellisense. Later on typing a dot bring the intellisense menu with the recommendation (`base.`), but if you <kbd>esc</kbd>, you can't bring it back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> anymore.And as I mentioned non of the <kbd>F1</kbd> ... <kbd>F12</kbd>. Wanted to know if this is common issue and if there is an easy fix.

It's *Windows 7 64-bit*, *Visual Studio 2013* Pro with *Resharper*.

**Attempts**

- Checked if the F5 key is mapped in *Visual Studio* and it is.
- Tried remapping the *Resharper* shortcuts from it's options. Didn't effect anything.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try disabling Resharper temporarily -- does it make a difference?

Comment: Suspended Resharper, closed VS and opened it back up and every shortcut is in function. @Cameron. Great suggestion. However. How can I make these two (Resharper & Xamarin to be friends)? Not that I really care about Resharper in this Project but would like to use it for the rest of the Projs for sure.

Comment: No idea :-) It was a shot in the dark. Try contacting the Resharper folks -- usually they're pretty good about trying to fix incompatibility bugs.

Comment: You're a good shot @Cameron. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue with disabling Resharper from Visual Studio menu,

Tools > Options > Resharper Platform > General > Suspend Now.

Restarted VS and then enabled the Resharper back.